# What is the meaning of "迷い" in the phrase 夜の街迷いし穢れの乱歩

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, classical-japanese, auxiliary-き

This phrase is from a song the translation of

"夜の街迷いし穢れの乱歩"

would be: Lost in a city at night, I take a random impure walk.

The question is: "迷い" in the dictionary means hesitation, perplexity, which does not look like its meaning in the sentence. 
   So I was wondering where did "迷い" come from? comes from the verb "迷う"？ if yes how did it become "迷い"?  and yet how does it bind directly to 街 no particles?  I know they give a lot of questions, can anyone explain me?  my language is portuguese so sorry for any grammar mistake.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65590/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23682/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

迷いし is an archaic variation of 迷った. It's still common in fiction, especially fantasy. See these questions:

- [Grammar of (verb)し(noun) such as in 選ばれし者](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14498/5010)
- [In "[Vます stem] + し+ [noun]" what does し mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18978/5010)
- [What does the kana 「し」 do in this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61564/5010)

As for 迷う itself, I personally feel its meaning is closer to "to wander about" rather than "to be lost" here, because it's clearly moving (乱歩). See [さ迷う](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%B7%E5%BE%A8%E3%81%86).

Note that 迷いし is a relative clause that modifies 穢れ, so it's the 穢れ ("impurity/corruption") itself that is wandering about. It's "steps of wandering impurity" rather than "I take an impure walk".